# Could not find field: "Name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am doing the Michael Hartl Rails 3 Tutorial, Chapter 8.4 pages 316-320. I run the users_spec.rb test and both tests don't pass with the following error:

```
Failures:

1) Users signup failure should not make a new user

Failure/Error: fill_in "Name", :with => ""
Webrat::NotFoundError:

Could not find field: "Name"

# ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:12:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:10:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Users signup success should make a new user

Failure/Error: fill_in "Name",             :with => "Example User"
Webrat::NotFoundError:

Could not find field: "Name"

# ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:28:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3.97 seconds

2 examples, 2 failures**
```

**MY USERS_SPEC.RB FILE -**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Users" do
  describe "signup" do
    describe "failure" do
      it "should not make a new user" do
        lambda do
          visit signup_path
          fill_in "Name",       :with => ""
          fill_in "Email",      :with => ""
          fill_in "Password",   :with => ""
          fill_in "Confirmation", :with => ""
          click_button
          response.should render_template('users/new')
          response.should have_selector("div#error_explanation")
        end.should_not change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "success" do
      it "should make a new user" do
        lambda do
          visit signup_path
          fill_in "Name",       :with => "Example User"
          fill_in "Email",      :with => "user@example.com"
          fill_in "Password",   :with => "foobar"
          fill_in "Confirmation", :with => "foobar"
          click_button
          response.should have_selector("div.flash.success",:content => "Welcome")
          response.should render_template('users/show')
        end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i solved the problem. I am using the Rails 3 Tutorial to make my authentication system for my own Website so i changed the Sign Up Form at app/views/users/new up a little bit from the original of Michael Hartls:

**Original** =

```
<div id="signupfield">
<%= f.label :name, "Name" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
```

**My own Edit**=

```
<div id="signupfield">
<%= f.label :name, "Username" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
```

The parentheses (Name & Username) are important because it goes in spec/requests/users_spec.rb:

**Original**=

```
lambda do
visit signup_path
fill_in "Name",  :with => "".......
```

**My Own Edit** =

```
lambda do   
visit signup_path       
fill_in "Username", :with => ""......
```

I got the test to pass completely, just remember whatever you put in the parentheses has to be the same as the view parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the Users table on your database first. And then, create the respective fields (name, email, password, confirmation).

Run the migrate (rake db:migrate)

And so, try to run the tests again.

Answer (score 0):

Print out the response to see what you're actually getting. You can also look at `log/test.log` to see if there was an exception or redirect on that request.

```
visit signup_path
puts response.body
```